# Calculate conditional expectation

Tags: probability, statistics

If $N\geq2$ and consider a population consisting of the first N positive entire numbers: {1,2,...,N}.
Let $$\mu=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^{N}i = \frac{N+1}{2}$$ be the population average and $$\sigma^2=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^{N} (x_i-\mu)^2 = \frac{N^2-1}{12}$$ be the population variance.

We draw a number two times and select without replacement.The first drawing is the stochastic variable X and the second Y.
Now I have to prove $$E[Y|X]=\frac{N\mu-X}{N-1}$$ but I don't know how to start. Can anybody help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For every $n$ in $\{1,2,\ldots,N\}$, conditionally on $X=n$, $Y$ is uniformly distributed on $\{1,2,\ldots,N\}\setminus\{n\}$. This last set has size $N-1$ hence
$$
E(Y\mid X=n)=\frac1{N-1}\sum_{1\leqslant i\leqslant N,i\ne n}i=\left(\frac1{N-1}\sum_{i=1}^Ni\right)-\frac{n}{N-1}.
$$
Can you finish?

Comment: Now I also want to proof E[XY]=$\mu^2-\frac{\sigma^2}{N-1}$. Can you give a hint how to come to this answer?

Comment: Hint: E(XY)=E(XE(Y|X)).

Comment: Thank you. $E(XY)=E(\frac{N\mu-X}{N-1}*X)=E(\frac{N \mu X}{N-1})-E(\frac{X^2}{N-1})$, but I don't get any further, I hope that you can help me again!

Comment: Surely you can compute $E(X)$ and $E(X^2)$, no?